# iOS Pass data, singleton, extern or via protocols?

Tags: ios, xcode, singleton, protocols, extern

Hy all,
I am really stuck at data passing in my iOS app.

First i have a class with TabBarController and inside another two ViewController.
It's a container view with a daily and weekly calendar views.

And i wanted to store the downloaded data in an NSDictionary with dates, so the calendar don't have to reload the data any time (only if the user force refresh).

So, should i store this data in an "extern NSDictionary" in the Container view?
Or should i create a SingletonClass and store the Dictionary there?
But will the SingletonClass released after the container view get released?

Or should i store the NSDictionary in the container view and then use methods via protocols to access the Dic? But how?

I checked a lot of tutorials and examples but i still don't know how to do it properly.
Thank you

Comment: So, you have a tab bar controller that has 2 tabs each with a view controller.  One VC shows daily and the other shows weekly calendar and the question was how to share data between these two controllers?

Comment: Yes,i wanted a class (or i extend the TabBarContrCalls) that can give back some data for a data (it downloads it if not have already).
Do i need to use singletons? But will they released after all included classes released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it inside the tabBarController and access it inside of the tabBar viewController instances, but I think you might be best off by just storing it inside of the NSUserDefaults..That way you can easily grab it from anywhere in your application without grabbing the tabBar instance.

I'd personally recommend creating a Singleton class that implements your NSUserDefaults like so (although you can just write and read directly to it if you'd like):

```
//DefaultsSingleton.h
@interface DefaultsSingleton : NSObject
{   
}

+(DefaultsSingleton*) sharedDefaultsSingleton;
@property(atomic,assign)NSDictionary *yourDictionary;
```

---

```
//DefaultsSingleton.m
@implementation DefaultsSingleton

SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(DefaultsSingleton)

-(NSDictionary *) yourDictionary
{
    return[ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"your_dictionary"];
}

-(void) setYourDictionary:(NSDictionary *)yourDictionary
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:yourDictionary];
}
```

Then just import this singleton file to wherever you want to access it and you can init new dictionaries with the values of it and create mutable copies, and then override the saved value whereever you'd like. Oh and you should also import Matt Gallagher's awesome SynthesizeSingleton class. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: Hy there,
I already use a singleton class with NSUserDefaults to store username, email address and previous data, like last used ViewController, type of the user and stuff like that.

But storing i want to make a dynamic and organized dictionary what is full of events, (days are the keys, then the objects are arrays, and inside more dictionary with the data).

So what if i store this Dics and its methods in the TabBarControllerView and then i access it with delegate methods, is it the best way to handle it?

BTW thanks for the reply

Comment: Yeah that sounds like it would work as long as your willing to reload your dictionaries each time the app is relaunched. Is that what your looking to do?